# Como colar uma lista do excel para o android studio e ficar organizado, com quebra de linhas?

Tags: java, android, microsoft-excel, android-layout

Lista no excel

[image: Uma lista no excel]

- `Relacionar o item`
- `Cidade`
- `Relacionar o item`
- `Afonso Bezerra`
- `Alexandria`
- `Alexandria`
- `Almino Afonso`
- `Alto do Rodrigues`
- `Angicos`
- `Angicos`
- `Apodi`
- `Apodi`

Como fazer isso no xml?

[image: Que nao fiquei assim.]

Pois como uma lista grande, e quero por mais de 2 colunas, não posso ficar colocando uma a uma, e sim no máximo  colar com colunas.

Comment: Mas o objetivo é por os textos que vem do excel numa `TextView` de um layout é isso ?

Comment: Sim. desde que fique organizados. Pque quero ter 2 ou 3 colunas . Quero que fique que nem o excel, separado com linhas e colunas, só que no layout ou numa textview

Comment: Isso já parece uma pergunta diferente. Então o que está a tentar é "replicar" um layout tipo o excel ? Incluindo nele os dados que já tem ?

Comment: Sim. os dados eu já tenho. eu quero somente colocar no layout de forma semelhante, linhas e colunas. Só que são muitos dados.... e eu não tenho como colocar um por um...

Comment: Cola em um bloco de notas, copia e cola no Android Studio. Eu sempre faço isso para outras plataformas. Se der certo me informe. Obrigado!!!

Comment: Já fiz isso! Mas não fica com quebra de linha... usar alguma formula  <br> funcionaria?